# How to write multiplication of series of numbers in factorial form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial

I want to write

$$1 \times 2 \times 3 \times \dotsb \times 1 \times 5 \times 9 \times 13 \times \dotsb$$

in factorial form, but I don't know how?

Comment: I don't see a meaningful way for you to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [multifactorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Multifactorials) notation:

$1 \times 2 \times 3 \times \dotsb \times n \times 1 \times 5 \times 9 \times \dotsb \times (4m+1) = n! \times (4m+1)!!!!$